# validating a column based on a value in another column

Tags: validation

I have a list which has [Status] and [% Complete] as columns.

In the [% Complete] column, I added a validation rule to pass validation when [Status]="Complete" AND [% Complete]=100, otherwise retunr an error.

My formula is:

```
=IF(AND([Status]="Complete",[% Complete]=100), "OK", "NOT OK")
```

But it's generating an error, what am I missing?

Comment: is this an excel conditional formula?

Comment: This is a validation formula for Sharepoint column 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use other columns in a column validation formula

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(Status="Completed",[% Complete]=1),"OK","NOT OK")
```

This works for me.  Note that 100% is 1 not 100.  Also that the standard is "Completed" and not "Complete" though this will depend on whether you have customised the choices.

However, that said, I do not really see anything wrong with your formula that would cause an error.